# Flagging Fake Answers

Tags: discussion, flagging

There are one or two users that I have come across who continually and persistently post fake answers. Why do I say fake? Because they always do one of the following:

1. Give a mathematically completely wrong answer that shows without doubt that he/she knows nothing about the topic! It is not simply mistakes. One very recent example claimed that any property of the domain of a continuous function carries over to the image! Worse still, he/she explicitly said that if the domain is open, the image is too!
2. Teach others via the comments below their wrong answer! How they have the cheek to do that without knowing what they are talking about I don't know.
3. Provide a computer program that checks only from 1 to $10^7$ or something, when the question explicitly asks for a proof!

My question is what to do about it. I've tried flagging some such answers in the past but it gave mixed results. Even for reason 3, which is clearly a valid reason (does not answer the question), my flag got rejected TWICE by moderators who apparently don't read comments on flags.

Note that I have on many occasions tried to tell them what is correct and also where their logical errors are, and once in a while some others also do that, but they always instead claim that people are subduing their correct mathematics. So it appears that I cannot stop such nonsense. Why is it that we cannot flag an answer for being wrong and have maybe 5 or so users with higher reputation judge and remove it if it is really wrong? I don't get why we allow non-answers to confuse viewers. I am very tired of downvoting their answers just because they persist on pretending to know things and teaching others complete falsehood.

So this question is not the same as [Don't flag wrong answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4731/dont-flag-wrong-answers), because I don't mind having wrong answers with honest intentions (in fact such answers with their comments could be useful for later readers to understand the mistakes made and also sharpen their understanding), but I don't see any use whatsoever for wrong answers with clearly wrong intentions.

Comment: As far as 3. goes, numerical verification is often useful to give someone confidence that they are probably not wasting their time attempting to prove that something is true. While it is probably the case that numerical verification is more appropriate as a comment, sometimes the result is too long or complicated to give in a comment, so people leave the results in an answer. In this case, they should preface their post with a disclaimer that it is a comment, but too long or complex to be a comment.

Comment: One issue is that such answers may superficially look ok and some people probably base their flag review on a quick glance when they should actually read the post. Sometimes a glance suffices, but not always, and it's sometimes hard to tell what the flagger thinks is wrong. Perhaps we should have a way to communicate to reviewers when the post should be read in detail by someone who understands the field.

Comment: @robjohn: I fully agree with having those kind of answers that you mention. However, the kind I am disgusted with are those for which the question is an elementary one (in some cases already having existing correct complete solutions!) but then this user comes along and says something along the lines of "It's very easy to write a program to solve it"...

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta: I'd be very glad if your suggested mechanism were in place. That would be at least 1 out of 3 problems down, and the most objective one too.

Comment: In general, don't flag wrong answers using a custom flag (those for $\small\blacklozenge$-moderator attention), as only moderators see them. Voting (downvoting, voting to close, and voting to delete) are how these posts should be dealt with. Moderators are not guaranteed to know every topic and so it is better for others to vote for closure or deletion. Thus, it is best to flag these so that [non-mods can see](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/841).

Comment: @robjohn: I did use "This is not an answer" flag for most of them, but stopped for (1) and (2) when I was told that presence of wrong answers is **accepted** by the community and they will not be removed based on incorrectness. Which is why there is nothing we can do except to downvote, which I feel is really ridiculous. Many such answers don't get viewed by people who know enough to judge the correctness, and so even get upvoted much more than people like me can downvote.

Comment: @user21820: people with enough reputation can vote to delete such answers. The reason that moderators don't usually vote to delete is that their votes are binding; that is, they delete the answer immediately. The community would rather have several people decide these things rather than a unilateral decision by a moderator. In some cases, however, a moderator will delete a question or answer unilaterally.

Comment: It says "Your answer," not "Your Good and Correct Answer." :) If you point out errors in comments, that's great; but I'm not sure why this upsets you as, in the long run, downvotes (including yours) should dissuade those users. Where do you draw the line? In some cases, not deleting your own answer you find out is incorrect is the right path of action (eg, it engendered helpful discussion), even if downvoted and so negatively impacting answerer.

Comment: @robjohn: The reason _I_ don't vote to delete such answers is not because my vote is binding, but rather that it is only reversible by another moderator, and so should be used in more extreme circumstances. That being said, the "low quality" queue is [where delete votes go to die](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/243671/214632). One may consider using a chatroom (perhaps [Jury Duty](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/2165/jury-duty), or even the main chatroom) to organise deletions of this kind. This is not exactly uncommon across SE.

Comment: @robjohn: Ah I see. I agree with requiring multiple people agree. But how to ask for "people with enough reputation" to look at those answers? On the one hand, if that works I don't mind at all. On the other hand, it seems a bit too high and so there aren't that many of them around, and I don't really want to waste their time on these.

Comment: @gnometorule: The downvotes don't dissuade them as I've already pointed out in my last comment before yours, because more people upvote their answers than people downvote, despite most of their answers being useless.

Comment: @user21820: to get people with enough reputation, you can always use the flags that are not mod-only. Those will add to queues for people with enough reputation to see.

Comment: @robjohn: Hmm.. then are you suggesting I continue to use those flags for such low quality answers? I thought I wasn't supposed to.

Comment: @user21820: low-quality answers should be downvoted. There is no flag that specifies low-quality answers. If they do not attempt to answer the question, then there is a flag for that.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, if someone consistently posts terrible answers they will be automatically blocked from posting new answers (and similarly for questions).

Comment: @NajibIdrissi Yes, but that only works if the answers get downvoted. Math users are stingy with downvotes in general (especially on answers, where they cost 1pt), and are generous with upvotes. Bad-faith semi-answers upvoted for the entertainment value is nothing unusual.

Comment: @Raff: If your hypothesis is true, it explains the phenomenon I am seeing. I'm more than glad to use up my downvotes on clearly nonsensical answers. All I have to do to get back the points is to answer one or two questions...

Comment: @Najib "As far as I'm aware, if someone consistently posts terrible answers they will be automatically blocked from posting new answers (and similarly for questions)" Two years later, are you still holding this view? My impression is that there may well be some mechanisms on the site which purport to do that, but that then they are clearly not very stringent.

Comment: @Did: Yes I still hold this view, because it is easy to get away with posting terrible answers. If you don't believe me I can easily find a couple of still active users who post literally fake answers, and few of their answers here and there are not fake, making a toxic combination. Note that I'm not classifying the answers in my most recent complaint as fake, but one of the answerers proudly refuses to admit error.

Comment: @user21820 Yes, this is my point, and the reason why I am interested to know if Najib's reasons to think otherwise two years ago, still hold in his view. As I said, my own experience is that users "consistently posting terrible answers" are **not** "automatically blocked from posting new answers".

Comment: @Did: Sorry I didn't notice you were directing your comment to Najib. Your experience fully agrees with mine. Also my experience includes the fact that the CRUDE room fails too.

Comment: @Did No, I don't hold these views anymore. Some users post garbage day in day out and aren't blocked. And due to the +10/-2 rule, they even accrue reputation in general.

Comment: @Najib OK, glad to know. In my view the site has an incredibly lenient approach to day-in-day-out-garbage-posters, shared by at least a part of the mod team (but probably not by every other se site). On math.se, it seems that no amount of crap answers is enough to have any actual consequence to their author.

Comment: @Did: I can actually understand that moderators feel their hands are a bit tied because they don't want to violate the network-wide attitude of letting the community evaluate answers. But for the special case of mathematics, I would rather have professional mathematicians be moderators and come down hard on nonsense. It's a wish not yet fulfilled.

Comment: @user21820 I get your point but I am pretty sure that, over time, some of these offenders have accumulated a sizeable amount of flags and of nonsensical answers, so much so that taking action against them would be quite legitimate *in the se system*. But nothing of the sort is coming. Add to this the systematic reprimands by some high rep users (sometines joined by some mods) against anybody mentioning that such and such answer is crap (which is never nicely enough done, it seems), and one reaches the conclusion that the tools to weed wrong content from the site exist but are not used.

Comment: @Did: Do you want to continue discussing in chat, say CRUDE? I think it is a combined failure of the SE system and the attitude of SE participants. The SE system can't penalize incorrect answers easily in general, since what will be the judge? Especially in borderline cases of users that post answers that are usually acceptable but nearly always riddled with serious misconceptions when it comes to things they don't understand. Acceptance of most of their answers make them too proud to admit serious conceptual errors.

Comment: @user21820 "CRUDE" No thanks (anyway, at this point, I think I mostly stated my views), but thanks for your thoughts, I appreciate that you expanded on them. A last remark though: *other SE sites act differently*. So, even though they surely have users "too proud to admit serious conceptual errors" as well, the general ethos there does not allow the behaviour of such users to prosper and become a nuisance.

Comment: The issue here is definitely present on a few other SE sites. There is one in particular that seems to actively encourage answers "so wrong I don't know where to start" on the basis of "this question is inherently subjective so the best we can do is ask for reasons to support the opinion". Conceptual or factual, they prosper because their content reflects the average knowledge of the community, itself a heavily biased sample of the population, and nobody wants to downvote something that agrees with deep-seated beliefs, regardless of disagreement with reality. @Did

Comment: @Nij This might be (although I am no expert enough to guess the site you are alluding to). Bear in mind though that mathematics being a domain of knowledge where the notions of "correct solution" and "wrong solution" are relevant, unmitigated, it is entirely this community's fault that they do not get rid of the blatant crap I am talking about. Likewise it was entirely "our" fault, a while ago, to elect as mod a user obviously unsuited to the task, and, more recently, to have elected as mod a user clearly at the most permissive end of the spectrum regarding answers to PSQs.

Answer (score 25):

In most cases, all you need to do for those is   **downvote** the answer and **leave a comment** explaining what is wrong with it. Partly for the benefit of the author, partly so that others will read the comment and downvote the answer too.

One can **vote to delete** an answer, but such votes require 20000 reputation and are available only for answers with negative score (accepted answers are protected from this too).

In  egregious cases, one may be able to summon a flash-mob of downvoters and delete voters from the chat.

As for **flags**, the two flags you may want to consider  are Very Low Quality  and Not An Answer.

- Very Low Quality is available only for posts with non-positive score. It is meant for unreadable or incomprehensible posts, where reader's reaction is not "this is wrong" but "what is this I don't even".
- Not An Answer is meant for texts that do not attempt to answer a question. E.g., something that should be posted as a comment, or as another question, or some irrelevant remark that should just be deleted.

These flags are not suitable for posts that *honestly attempt* to answer the question, even unsuccessfully. For those, see the first paragraph.

Comment: Yes I agree with all your points, however the users I am referring to are **not honestly attempting to answer** the question. If my judgement is right, they are merely seeking attention. This would not be a problem except that they have completely no qualms in pretending to teach other, resulting only in confusion or in some cases false understanding. I am very glad to see honest attempts at an answer, and for those I very gladly give comments detailing what went wrong. But it is simply a waste of time and effort to do so for the problematic users I am referring to.

Comment: As for the summoning part, I'm not sure if that kind of behaviour is acceptable to the rest of the community, though I don't mind doing that if only to get rid of sheer nonsense quickly.

Comment: Just drop a link `[Trolling/bad-faith answer](url)` into the chat, and let others decide what to do.

Comment: Ah okay sure thanks!

Comment: I did it in the reopen/undelete/close/delete chat-room. Nothing happened. As I expected. No one cares. `<sarcasm>` Falsehoods are fine. `</sarcasm>`